# Subgroups of the Heisenberg group over the integers

Tags: group-theory

I'm looking for a subgroup, $H$, of the Heisenberg group 
$G = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z} \\
0 & 1 & \mathbb{Z} \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ with the following properties:

1. $H \cap Z(G) = e$;
2. $[G:HZ(G)]<\infty$.

I'm not certain that this subgroup exists. But if it did, since $Z(G) = [G,G]$, $H$ would have to be abelian as otherwise $e \neq [H,H]\leq Z(G)$. I also think that $H$ would have to be quite 'big' - maybe in terms of Hirsch length - as otherwise you'd never get finite index. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: There is no such subgroup. To get $|G:HZ(G)| < \infty$, $H$ would have to be free abelian of rank $2$, and there is no such subgroup that intersects the $Z(G)$ trivially.